# What will be syntax of Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which have structure like-

```
Table1->propiedad

codigo   codpropietario

 14       17
 15       16
 16       15
 17       8
 18       14


table2->wp_posts

ID        codigo

1091       17
1090       16
1089       15
1088       14
```

I want third table which will have following data from above tables-

```
   codigo      ID

    14         1091
    15         1090
    16         1089
    17          
    18         1088
```

Comment: The question is not clear whether it is to create a view or exporting data to another table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a third table.  As a matter of fact, it would be a bad design.

You want a JOIN:

```
select a.codigo, b.ID
from propiedad as a
join wp_posts as b
on a.codpropietario = b.codigo
order by a.codigo
```